# Error: Transaction reverted: function call to a non-contract account when calling flashLoan on balancer

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, testing

I have forked the polygone mainnet in hardhat and when I call the makeFlashLoan function in my test I get the following error.
`Error: Transaction reverted: function call to a non-contract account`
Here is my contract

```js
// interfaces here
contract BalancerFlashLoan is IFlashLoanRecipient {
    address public vaultAddress = 0xBA12222222228d8Ba445958a75a0704d566BF2C8;
    IVault public VAULT = IVault(vaultAddress);
    address private constant Uniswap_v2_router =
        0xa5E0829CaCEd8fFDD4De3c43696c57F7D7A678ff;
    address public owner;

    constructor() {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }
    function makeFlashLoan(
        IERC20[] memory tokens,
        uint256[] memory amounts,
        address[] memory arbTokens // bytes memory userData
    ) public {
        console.log("inside flashloan function");
        bytes memory userData = encodeAddressArray(arbTokens);
        // this call to vault contract results in failing error
        VAULT.flashLoan(this, tokens, amounts, userData);
    }

    function receiveFlashLoan(
        IERC20[] memory tokens,
        uint256[] memory amounts,
        uint256[] memory feeAmounts,
        bytes calldata userData
    ) external override {
        require(IVault(msg.sender) == VAULT, "Only Vault can call");
        console.log("inside the receive flashloan");

        address[] memory arbTokens = decodeAddressArray(userData);
       // returns the flashloan after some custom logic 
        _returnTokensToVault(tokens, amounts, feeAmounts);
    }
    // other internal functions here
   }
```

Here is my hardhat config

```js
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.19",
  networks: {
    forking: {
      url: "https://polygon-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/{my-api-key-goes-here}",
      chainId: 137,
      blockNumber: 42001660,
    },
  },
};
```

here is my test

```js
 describe("BalancerFlashLoan", async () => {
  const vaultAddress = "0xBA12222222228d8Ba445958a75a0704d566BF2C8";
  let BalancerFlashLoan;
  let balancerFlashLoan;

   beforeEach(async () => {
    BalancerFlashLoan = await ethers.getContractFactory("BalancerFlashLoan");
    balancerFlashLoan = await BalancerFlashLoan.deploy();
    await balancerFlashLoan.deployed();
  });

    it("should receive the flashloan", async () => {
    const VAULT = await balancerFlashLoan.VAULT();
    const regex = new RegExp(VAULT, "i");
    expect(vaultAddress).to.match(regex);

    await balancerFlashLoan.makeFlashLoan(
      ["0x1BFD67037B42Cf73acF2047067bd4F2C47D9BfD6"],
      [20000],
      [
        "0x0d500B1d8E8eF31E21C99d1Db9A6444d3ADf1270",
        "0xee7666aACAEFaa6efeeF62ea40176d3eB21953B9",
        "0x7ceB23fD6bC0adD59E62ac25578270cFf1b9f619",
        "0xB5C064F955D8e7F38fE0460C556a72987494eE17",
        "0x0d500B1d8E8eF31E21C99d1Db9A6444d3ADf1270",
      ]
    );
  });
 })
```

I am passing the correct vault addresses and you can check the docs [here](https://docs.balancer.fi/reference/contracts/deployment-addresses/polygon.html#core).
I forked the  polygon using `npx hardhat node`. The vault contract is present on the mainnet and it does not makes sense for the test to throw "non contract account" error
Example showing how to take flashLoan: https://docs.balancer.fi/reference/contracts/flash-loans.html#example-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with the vault contract instance when you're forking the Polygon mainnet.

First set the `live` flag to `true` for the forking network

```
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.19",
  networks: {
    forking: {
      url: "https://polygon-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/{my-api-key-goes-here}",
      chainId: 137,
      blockNumber: 42001660,
      live: true,
    },
  },
};
```

then modify the test so that it it clearly use the forking network, also use `ethers.provider.getContractAt()` function, dont forget to replace the my-`api-key-goes-here` with your API.

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

describe("BalancerFlashLoan", async () => {
  const vaultAddress = "0xBA12222222228d8Ba445958a75a0704d566BF2C8";
  let BalancerFlashLoan;
  let balancerFlashLoan;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await network.provider.request({
      method: "hardhat_reset",
      params: [{
        forking: {
          jsonRpcUrl: "https://polygon-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/{my-api-key-goes-here}",
          blockNumber: 42001660
        }
      }]
    });

    BalancerFlashLoan = await ethers.getContractFactory("BalancerFlashLoan");
    balancerFlashLoan = await BalancerFlashLoan.deploy();
    await balancerFlashLoan.deployed();

    // Create an instance of the vault contract
    balancerFlashLoan.VAULT = await ethers.getContractAt("IVault", vaultAddress);
  });

  // The rest of your test code
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much I have my test working. Can you please link the resource from where you got the solution because I don't see any mention of a hard reset here: https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/guides/forking-other-networks